# How to create ACL rules for an AWS S3 VPC Endpoint via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to set up a VPC Endpoint for S3 via Terraform.

To do so, I need to add rules to my acl for *all* of the CIDR blocks used by S3 in the appropriate region.

I can get the CIDR blocks using the `aws_prefix_list` data source.

The problem is then adding the rules.
Rules need to be added one at a time via the `aws_network_acl_rule` resource.

However, without knowing in advance how many CIDR blocks will be returned, there is no way to enumerate through them (Terraform does not let us simply count the results).

I don't want to have to hardcode the number of results to expect (which differs between region and over time).

The following fails with the error `* aws_network_acl_rule.private_s3: aws_network_acl_rule.private_s3: value of 'count' cannot be computed` because it does not know at plan time how many results will be returned.

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "private_s3" {
  vpc_id       = "{var.vpc_id}"
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.us-west-2.s3"
}

data "aws_prefix_list" "private_s3" {
  prefix_list_id = "${aws_vpc_endpoint.private_s3.prefix_list_id}"
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "bar" {
  vpc_id       = "{var.vpc_id}"
}

resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "private_s3" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_prefix_list.private_s3.cidr_blocks)}"

  network_acl_id = "${aws_network_acl.bar.id}"
  rule_number    = 200
  egress         = false
  protocol       = "tcp"
  rule_action    = "allow"
  cidr_block     = "${data.aws_prefix_list.private_s3.cidr_blocks[count.index]}"
  from_port      = 443
  to_port        = 443
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried to do to achieve this because I would have expected you to be able to count the CIDR blocks retrieved by `aws_prefix_list` and then loop through them creating NACLs easily enough.

Comment: Thanks - I have added some detail above. This fails with the dreaded `value of 'count' cannot be computed` error because the number of results being returned may change.

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue and they'r working on it for future versions: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10857 https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12570